# lpr does not see default printer - why?

Tags: printing, printer, cups, lpr

I've set my only printer to be the default printer via CUPS, which lpstat confirms

```
$ lpstat -p -d
printer MFC-9840CDW is idle.  enabled since Fri 03 Jun 2016 09:05:46 AM
        Online
system default destination: MFC-9840CDW
```

Nevertheless, trying to print something via lpr does not work as it should:

```
$ lpr  rn2016129.pdf
lpr: Error - no default destination available.
```

(same is true for lp)

It is only when I explicitly set the printer name for lpr, things work:

```
$ lpr  -P MFC-9840CDW rn2016129.pdf
```

The obvious question is: why?

Comment: What package is providing your `lpr` command?  I'm using the one in Debian's `cups-bsd` package, which is designed to integrate with CUPS and should see your CUPS default as the default.  If you have a different package (e.g. `lpr` or `lprng`) then you may need to configure it to integrate with CUPS (e.g. by editing `/etc/printcap`)

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://127.0.0.1:631/printers/

Pull down Administration --> Set as server default

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).